# cannot render HTML with PUG/JUD

Tags: node.js, express, pug, pugjs

I am trying to render .jade templates as HTML via command line. I have added the CLI dependency. I have spent hours on syntax but keep getting the same error. I know it says inconsistent indentation but I cannot see where.

```
  watching views/_includes/sharedFunctions.jade
  rendered views/_includes/sharedFunctions.html
  watching views/add.jade
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'views/layout.pug'
    at views//add.jade line 1
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
    at Function.read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-load/index.js:69:13)
    at Object.load.string.read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:141:25)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-load/index.js:24:25
    at walkAST (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-load/node_modules/pug-walk/index.js:21:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-load/node_modules/pug-walk/index.js:98:20
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at walkAndMergeNodes (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-load/node_modules/pug-walk/index.js:97:18)
  watching views/error.jade
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'views/layout.pug'
    at views//error.jade line 1
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
    at Function.read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-load/index.js:69:13)
    at Object.load.string.read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:141:25)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-load/index.js:24:25
    at walkAST (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-load/node_modules/pug-walk/index.js:21:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-load/node_modules/pug-walk/index.js:98:20
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at walkAndMergeNodes (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-load/node_modules/pug-walk/index.js:97:18)
  watching views/find.jade
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'views/layout.pug'
    at views//find.jade line 1
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
    at Function.read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-load/index.js:69:13)
    at Object.load.string.read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:141:25)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-load/index.js:24:25
    at walkAST (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-load/node_modules/pug-walk/index.js:21:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-load/node_modules/pug-walk/index.js:98:20
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at walkAndMergeNodes (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-load/node_modules/pug-walk/index.js:97:18)
  watching views/index.jade
  watching views/layout.jade
    as a dependency of views/index.jade
  rendered views/index.html
  watching views/layout.jade
  rendered views/layout.html
  watching views/login.jade
Error: views//login.jade:34:9
    32|                 | Sign in
    33|               p
  > 34|       .row
----------------^
    35|         .col-sm-6.col-md-4.col-md-offset-4
    36|           button.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.btn-block(href='#') Sign Up          
    37|       .row

Inconsistent indentation. Expecting either 4 or 8 spaces/tabs.
    at makeError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-lexer/node_modules/pug-error/index.js:32:13)
    at Lexer.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:58:15)
    at Lexer.indent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:1208:18)
    at Lexer.callLexerFunction (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:1315:23)
    at Lexer.advance (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:1354:15)
    at Lexer.callLexerFunction (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:1315:23)
    at Lexer.getTokens (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:1371:12)
    at lex (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:12:42)
    at Object.load.string.lex (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:93:27)
    at Function.loadString [as string] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-load/index.js:44:24)
```

Comment: First error ENOENT says it can't find layout.pug and it's obvious that you have layout.jade so rename it. The *Inconsistent indentation* error means you are either mixing tabs and spaces or not using 4 or 8 spaces. I don't know how it works in your editor but in sublime text you can set desired indentation by one click and also fix mixed indentations.

Comment: I did try change the extension to .pug and got the same issue before posting. If I just add pug index.jade with layout.jade and layout.pug in the directory I get /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pug-cli/node_modules/pug/node_modules/pug-load/index.js:27
          throw ex;
          ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'layout.pug'